# Remove duplicate rows in a grouped data.frame R-lang

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Based on `timestamp` column, last two rows are same as the 2 rows before that, only difference being timestamp. I would like to clean such similar row groups, based on timestamp, **keeping only the earliest set of duplicate row groups**. Simply using `!duplicated` excluding the `timestamp` gets rid of additional rows.

Also the rows might contain a lot of NA values, for the sample can be seen on last 4 rows, columns 7-8.

Also if possible, can we give as input the columns based on which duplicates be determined and group them by more than one column, e.g. group the data.frame by timestamp and strike columns.

Below is the data.frame.

```
dput(opbook)
```

Output

```
structure(list(strike = c(8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 
8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 8000L, 8100L, 
8000L, 8100L), OI.call = c(3445925L, 3633225L, 3445925L, 3633225L, 
3445925L, 3633225L, 3445925L, 3633225L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 
3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 3573575L, 3432375L, 
3573575L, 3124300L, 3529925L, 3124300L, 3529925L), changeOI.call = c(-65325L, 
-159500L, -65325L, -159500L, -65325L, -159500L, -65325L, -159500L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, 
-219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, 
-78875L, -219150L, -78875L, -219150L, -386950L, -262800L, -386950L, 
-262800L), volume.call = c(758973L, 857367L, 758973L, 857367L, 
758973L, 857367L, 758973L, 857367L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 
766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 
866243L, 766572L, 866243L, 766572L, 866243L), IV.call = c(13.74, 
14.49, 13.74, 14.49, 13.74, 14.49, 13.74, 14.49, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 
14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 14.11, 14.66, 
14.11, 14.66, 13.38, 14.2, 13.38, 14.2), LTP.call = c(90.95, 
48.25, 90.95, 48.25, 90.95, 48.25, 90.95, 48.25, 90, 47.75, 90, 
47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75), bidQ.call = c(675L, 75L, 675L, 
75L, 675L, 75L, 675L, 75L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 
50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 50L, 
25L, 50L, NA, NA, NA, NA), bidP.call = c(90.6, 48.15, 90.6, 48.15, 
90.6, 48.15, 90.6, 48.15, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 
89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 47.5, 89.7, 
47.5), askP.call = c(90.95, 48.3, 90.95, 48.3, 90.95, 48.3, 90.95, 
48.3, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 
90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75, 90, 47.75), askQ.call = c(500L, 
150L, 500L, 150L, 500L, 150L, 500L, 150L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 
25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L, 
7075L, 25L, 7075L, 25L), TIMESTAMP = c("2015-06-15 15:29", "2015-06-15 15:29", 
"2015-06-15 15:29", "2015-06-15 15:29", "2015-06-15 15:30", "2015-06-15 15:30", 
"2015-06-15 15:30", "2015-06-15 15:30", "2015-06-15 15:31", "2015-06-15 15:31", 
"2015-06-15 15:31", "2015-06-15 15:31", "2015-06-15 15:32", "2015-06-15 15:32", 
"2015-06-15 15:32", "2015-06-15 15:32", "2015-06-15 15:33", "2015-06-15 15:33", 
"2015-06-15 15:33", "2015-06-15 15:33", "2015-06-15 15:34", "2015-06-15 15:34", 
"2015-06-15 15:34", "2015-06-15 15:34", "2015-06-15 15:35", "2015-06-15 15:35", 
"2015-06-15 15:35", "2015-06-15 15:35", "2015-06-15 15:36", "2015-06-15 15:36", 
"2015-06-15 15:36", "2015-06-15 15:36", "2015-06-15 15:37", "2015-06-15 15:37", 
"2015-06-15 15:37", "2015-06-15 15:37", "2015-06-15 15:38", "2015-06-15 15:38", 
"2015-06-15 15:38", "2015-06-15 15:38", "2015-06-15 15:39", "2015-06-15 15:39", 
"2015-06-15 15:39", "2015-06-15 15:39", "2015-06-15 15:40", "2015-06-15 15:40", 
"2015-06-15 15:40", "2015-06-15 15:40", "2015-06-15 15:41", "2015-06-15 15:41", 
"2015-06-15 15:41", "2015-06-15 15:41", "2015-06-15 15:42", "2015-06-15 15:42", 
"2015-06-15 15:42", "2015-06-15 15:42", "2015-06-15 15:43", "2015-06-15 15:43", 
"2015-06-15 15:43", "2015-06-15 15:43", "2015-06-15 15:44", "2015-06-15 15:44", 
"2015-06-15 15:44", "2015-06-15 15:44", "2015-06-15 15:45", "2015-06-15 15:45", 
"2015-06-15 15:45", "2015-06-15 15:45", "2015-06-15 15:46", "2015-06-15 15:46", 
"2015-06-15 15:46", "2015-06-15 15:46", "2015-06-15 15:47", "2015-06-15 15:47", 
"2015-06-15 15:47", "2015-06-15 15:47", "2015-06-15 15:48", "2015-06-15 15:48", 
"2015-06-15 15:48", "2015-06-15 15:48", "2015-06-15 15:49", "2015-06-15 15:49", 
"2015-06-15 15:49", "2015-06-15 15:49", "2015-06-15 15:50", "2015-06-15 15:50", 
"2015-06-15 15:50", "2015-06-15 15:50", "2015-06-15 15:51", "2015-06-15 15:51", 
"2015-06-15 15:51", "2015-06-15 15:51", "2015-06-15 15:52", "2015-06-15 15:52", 
"2015-06-15 15:52", "2015-06-15 15:52", "2015-06-15 15:53", "2015-06-15 15:53", 
"2015-06-15 15:53", "2015-06-15 15:53", "2015-06-15 15:54", "2015-06-15 15:54", 
"2015-06-15 15:54", "2015-06-15 15:54", "2015-06-15 15:55", "2015-06-15 15:55", 
"2015-06-15 15:55", "2015-06-15 15:55", "2015-06-15 15:56", "2015-06-15 15:56", 
"2015-06-15 15:56", "2015-06-15 15:56", "2015-06-15 15:57", "2015-06-15 15:57", 
"2015-06-15 15:57", "2015-06-15 15:57", "2015-06-15 15:58", "2015-06-15 15:58", 
"2015-06-15 15:58", "2015-06-15 15:58", "2015-06-15 15:59", "2015-06-15 15:59", 
"2015-06-15 15:59", "2015-06-15 15:59", "2015-06-15 16:00", "2015-06-15 16:00", 
"2015-06-15 16:00", "2015-06-15 16:00", "2015-06-15 16:01", "2015-06-15 16:01", 
"2015-06-15 16:01", "2015-06-15 16:01", "2015-06-15 16:02", "2015-06-15 16:02", 
"2015-06-15 16:02", "2015-06-15 16:02", "2015-06-15 16:03", "2015-06-15 16:03", 
"2015-06-15 16:03", "2015-06-15 16:03", "2015-06-15 16:04", "2015-06-15 16:04", 
"2015-06-15 16:04", "2015-06-15 16:04", "2015-06-15 16:05", "2015-06-15 16:05", 
"2015-06-15 16:05", "2015-06-15 16:05", "2015-06-15 16:06", "2015-06-15 16:06", 
"2015-06-15 16:06", "2015-06-15 16:06", "2015-06-15 16:07", "2015-06-15 16:07", 
"2015-06-15 16:07", "2015-06-15 16:07", "2015-06-15 16:08", "2015-06-15 16:08", 
"2015-06-15 16:08", "2015-06-15 16:08", "2015-06-15 16:09", "2015-06-15 16:09", 
"2015-06-15 16:09", "2015-06-15 16:09", "2015-06-15 16:10", "2015-06-15 16:10", 
"2015-06-15 16:10", "2015-06-15 16:10", "2015-06-15 16:11", "2015-06-15 16:11", 
"2015-06-15 16:11", "2015-06-15 16:11", "2015-06-15 16:12", "2015-06-15 16:12", 
"2015-06-15 16:12", "2015-06-15 16:12", "2015-06-15 16:13", "2015-06-15 16:13", 
"2015-06-15 16:13", "2015-06-15 16:13", "2015-06-15 16:14", "2015-06-15 16:14", 
"2015-06-15 16:14", "2015-06-15 16:14", "2015-06-15 16:15", "2015-06-15 16:15", 
"2015-06-15 16:15", "2015-06-15 16:15", "2015-06-15 16:16", "2015-06-15 16:16", 
"2015-06-15 16:16", "2015-06-15 16:16", "2015-06-15 16:17", "2015-06-15 16:17", 
"2015-06-15 16:17", "2015-06-15 16:17", "2015-06-15 16:18", "2015-06-15 16:18", 
"2015-06-15 16:18", "2015-06-15 16:18", "2015-06-15 16:19", "2015-06-15 16:19", 
"2015-06-15 16:19", "2015-06-15 16:19", "2015-06-15 16:20", "2015-06-15 16:20", 
"2015-06-15 16:20", "2015-06-15 16:20", "2015-06-15 16:21", "2015-06-15 16:21", 
"2015-06-15 16:21", "2015-06-15 16:21", "2015-06-15 16:22", "2015-06-15 16:22", 
"2015-06-15 16:22", "2015-06-15 16:22", "2015-06-15 16:23", "2015-06-15 16:23", 
"2015-06-15 16:23", "2015-06-15 16:23", "2015-06-15 16:24", "2015-06-15 16:24", 
"2015-06-15 16:24", "2015-06-15 16:24", "2015-06-15 16:25", "2015-06-15 16:25", 
"2015-06-15 16:25", "2015-06-15 16:25", "2015-06-15 16:26", "2015-06-15 16:26", 
"2015-06-15 16:26", "2015-06-15 16:26", "2015-06-15 16:27", "2015-06-15 16:27", 
"2015-06-15 16:27", "2015-06-15 16:27", "2015-06-15 16:28", "2015-06-15 16:28", 
"2015-06-15 16:28", "2015-06-15 16:28", "2015-06-15 16:29", "2015-06-15 16:29", 
"2015-06-15 16:29", "2015-06-15 16:29", "2015-06-15 16:30", "2015-06-15 16:30", 
"2015-06-15 16:30", "2015-06-15 16:30", "2015-06-15 16:31", "2015-06-15 16:31", 
"2015-06-15 16:31", "2015-06-15 16:31", "2015-06-15 16:32", "2015-06-15 16:32", 
"2015-06-15 16:32", "2015-06-15 16:32", "2015-06-15 16:33", "2015-06-15 16:33", 
"2015-06-15 16:33", "2015-06-15 16:33", "2015-06-15 16:34", "2015-06-15 16:34", 
"2015-06-15 16:34", "2015-06-15 16:34", "2015-06-15 16:35", "2015-06-15 16:35", 
"2015-06-15 16:35", "2015-06-15 16:35")), .Names = c("strike", 
"OI.call", "changeOI.call", "volume.call", "IV.call", "LTP.call", 
"bidQ.call", "bidP.call", "askP.call", "askQ.call", "TIMESTAMP"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -268L))
```

Hope this is a MWE and the problem has been explained sufficiently.

Comment: If I understood correctly you could try `library(dplyr); distinct(opbook)` since it seems that your data is already ordered by timestamp (increasingly).

Comment: Had the timestamps been not unique it would've worked. But for each timestamp entry there is a set of rows. I need such duplicate groups be removed except the group with earliest timestamp. But I can't simply do `opbook[ !duplicated(opbook[, -11])]` because that will remove many previous rows with much earlier timestamps.